# What to set href to on a react component with an onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have an anchor element set like this;

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleNewFormToggle}>
  <i className="ml-20 glyphicon glyphicon-plus"/>
</a>
```

But this fails eslint with `jsx-ally/href-no-hash`.

`javascript:void()` is out for xss reasons and no href fails with:

`jsx-ally/no-static-element-interactions`

so what should I set it to?

Comment: try to set the href on non exists div?

Comment: What don't you remove `href` attribute, if you don't have a work with that?

Comment: i've tried that and mentioned it in the post

Comment: Why not just make it a button?

Answer (score 1):

If your linting complains, you could leave the `href="#"` in the `a` tag. Then in the `handleNewFormToggle` you can prevent the default action of the click event:

```
handeNewFormToggle(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Alternatively, change your linting rules to allow you to remove the href tag :)